# Error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument

Tags: c++, string, c++11, double

I have the following code for dealing with doubles:

```
static bool
double_param(const char ** p, double * ptr_val)
{
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    double v = strtod(*p, &end);
    if (*p == end || errno) return false;
    *p = end;
    *ptr_val = v;
    return true;
}
```

This code is used to check whether passed double parameter is invalid like so:

```
if (!double_param(&p, &b1)) //p is pointer and b1 is parameter.
        //throw error;
```

And, I need to write an equivalent code for dealing with string of 3 characters long. I've gotten this on my own:

```
static bool
string_param(const char ** p, const string * ptr_val)
{
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    int v = strtol(*p, &end, 10);
    if (*p == end || errno) return false;
    *p = end;
    *ptr_val = v;
    return true;
}
```

but I get the following compile error:

```
error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 (*ptr_val) = v;
            ^
```

Any suggestions are appreciated to get around this error. Also, please point out the mistake in my code and explain a little so that I can understand better and learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are assigning to `*ptr_val` then it cannot be `const` in the function's signature.  You have to pick one, is it going to change (not const) or is not going to (const)?

Comment: +1 GuyGreer Oh, why do I always keep putting const with string. Almost a muscle memory. Thanks for pointing that out. That literally was the only thing causing compile error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*ptr_val` is a pointer to a `const string`. You are trying to change the value of a `const string`, which of course you cannot do.

You can instead do a const pointer like this: `string * const ptr_val`

This means that you can change the value of the data the pointer is pointing to, but you cannot change what the pointer points to.